# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, tuples, attributeerror

So I have been writing a code to standardize the elements of a matrix and the function I used is as follows:

```
def preprocess(Data):
    if stdn ==True:
       st=np.empty((Data.shape[0],Data.shape[1]))
       for i in xrange(0,Data.shape[0]):
           st[i,0]=Data[i,0]
       for i in xrange(1,Data.shape[1]):
           st[:,i]=((Data[:,i]-np.min(Data[:,i]))/(np.ptp(Data[:,i])))       
           np.random.shuffle(st)
       return st
    else:
       return Data
```

It works very well outside the class but when used inside of it it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Any idea on how I can fix it??

P.S. This is a KNN classification code.

Comment: Maybe try converting your `Data` into a `numpy.array`?

Comment: What is `Data`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the error you posted, `Data` is of type tuple and there is no attribute `shape` defined for data. You could try casting `Data` when you call your `preprocess` function, e.g.:

```
preprocess(numpy.array(Data))
```

Answer (score 0):

`.shape` is an attribute of numpy ndarrays and tuples don't have such attributes but it's possible to call `numpy.shape` on a tuple to get its "shape".

```py
import numpy as np
sh = np.shape(Data)
```

In general (not for OP), it's more useful to get the length of tuples:

```py
len(Data)
```